Cross origin cookies not visible in browser devtools, but still working
I have a MERN stack app, frontend on frontend.local and backend on backend.local. I have CORS set up. I'm using express-session.
When a user logs in, I set a session id, and it automatically sends a cookie (sameSite=None) back to the browser (req.session.userId = myUserId).
What I observe is that the cookie is not visible in the frontend devtools application tab (guessing since the domains are different). However, the authentication still works - somehow when I make requests to the backend, the cookie is included in the request. So,

Why does cookie sending mechanism work? Where is that authentication cookie really stored? I thought I couldn't set cross-origin cookies.
I wanted to add CSRF token mechanism to the app, but even if I write httpOnly: false, the cookie value is not visible/accessible to my frontend. How can I fix this?

Below are examples of frontend requests/responses to/from the server.


